# Tensorflow subtract returns wrong values

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

absolute tensorflow beginner here. I am trying to construct two random tensors and subtract them for an assignment. However I seem to have some issues with understanding how exactly the subtraction process works.

```
x=tf.random_normal([5],seed=123456)
y=tf.random_normal([5],seed=987654)
print(sess.run(x),sess.run(y))
```

I get the following outputs:

```
[ 0.38614973  2.97522092 -0.85282576 -0.57114178 -0.43243945]
[-0.43865281  0.08617876 -2.17495966 -0.24574816 -1.94319296]
```

But when I try

```
print(sess.run(x-y))
```

I get

```
[-1.88653958 -0.03917438  0.87480474  0.40511152  0.52793759]
```

Now if I run

```
print(sess.run(tf.subtract(x,y)))
```

I also get other wrong values.

```
[-1.97681355  1.10086703  1.41172433  1.55840468  0.04344697]
```

I hope somebody can help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operation not work properly in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129480/operation-not-work-properly-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you executes `x - y` multiple times since each time `x` and `y` will be assigned a different value. This is because when you write something like `x=tf.random_normal([5],seed=123456)`
 There really isn't any actual computation. TensorFlow is just constructing an operation node within the static computation graph. It is when you do `sess.run()` real computation happens.

So, consider the `x=tf.random_norm([5], seed=123456)` as a random number generator. The first time you call `sess.run()`, `x` has initial seed value `123456`. But the second time you call `sess.run()` the state of the random number generator has already changed, so the value will be different.

You can verify this by running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.random_normal([5], seed=123456)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(x)
    sess.run(x)
    sess.run(x)
```

The output will be

```
[ 0.38614973,  2.97522092, -0.85282576, -0.57114178, -0.43243945]
[-1.41140664, -0.50017339,  1.59816611,  0.07829454, -0.36143178]
[-1.10523391, -0.15264226,  1.79153454,  0.42320547,  0.26876169]
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour actually has to do with how the seed of your normal works, and how the session evaluates your nodes.

Tensorflow will use the seed of your random normal nodes when it creates them - **not when it runs them** :

```
>>> sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
>>> x = tf.random_normal([5], seed=123456)
>>> sess.run(x)
array([ 0.38614976,  2.97522116, -0.85282576, -0.57114178, -0.43243945], dtype=float32)
>>> sess.run(x)
array([-1.41140664, -0.50017333,  1.59816611,  0.07829454, -0.36143178], dtype=float32)
```

You can see that the values change when running `x` a second time.
Running `sess.run(x-y)` will actually run `x` (i.e. generate random numbers), then `y` (i.e. generate other random numbers), then `x-y`. Since you're not reinitializing the random generator with the seed before running `tf.subtract(x,y)`, you get different results.